# How to pass function as props from one functional component to another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I'm passing a function as prop from one functional component(Dashboard) to another (Event).However, When I'm clicking the button on the child component which holds the passed function prop on the onClick value , it throws an error.

**Uncaught TypeError: deleteEvent is not a function**

This my deleteEvent fucntion in Dashboard

```
  const deleteEvent = async (id) => {
    try {
      await Axios.delete(`/event/${id}`);
      const events = data.events.filter((event) => event.id !== id);
      setData({ ...data, events: events });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

This is how I'm rendring events in Dashboard.

```
{data.events.map((event, idx) => (
        <Event key={`event${idx}`} event={event} delete={() => deleteEvent} />
      ))}
```

Here's my Event.jsx

```
const Event = ({
  event: { id, name, price, duration, schedule },
  delete: { deleteEvent },
}) => {
  console.log(deleteEvent);
  return (
    <div className="event" key={id}>
      <p>Name: {name}</p>
      <p>Price: {price}</p>
      <p>Duration - {duration}</p>
      <p>Schedule</p>
      {Object.keys(schedule).map((day) => (
        <p key={day}>
          {day} -{' '}
          {schedule[day].map((slot, idx) => (
            <span key={idx}>
              {slot.start} - {slot.start}
            </span>
          ))}
        </p>
      ))}
      <button type="button" onClick={() => deleteEvent(id)}>
        Delete Event{' '}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

When I click the button , it thorws **Uncaught TypeError: deleteEvent is not a function** error.

What am I doing wrong ? I've done this using class based components before.

Comment: I think you're destructuring when it should just be  `delete: deleteEvent,` if you want to just rename it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! yeah, it solved the problem

Comment: @MattAft should I delete the question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're passing in the delete() function you are creating an anonymous function that returns the delete() function handle, instead of passing the function itself in.

Where you have

`delete={() => deleteEvent} />`

you could just pass the function itself as a prop

`delete={deleteEvent} />`

In the destructuring inside the `Event` code you would just need to access the function back out under the `delete` key instead of wrapping it in a second set of curleys to pull an object

`delete: deleteEvent`